# Spring Security CSRF: How to retrieve token in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf

I can see how to include the CSRF token in a JSP form, simply include the line

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

and you're done.
But, how can I get the parameter name and token in one of my @Controler classes? I've looked through docs and found nothing on this, and also looked through both Model and HttpSession attributes and failed to find it.

Answer (score 5):

you can retrieve the token use:

```
CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
```

You can have the **request** in the controller method parameter list.